# how to convert python requests http to flutter?

Tags: python, flutter, http

[image]
In python, this code is running and get response like screen shot.

I need this code in flutter. so i write the code like this.

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:html/parser.dart';
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';
void main() async {
  var url = 'https://www.lottecinema.co.kr/LCWS/Ticketing/TicketingData.aspx';

  var dic = {
    "paramList": {
      "MethodName": "GetPlaySequence",
      "channelType": "HO",
      "osType": "W",
      "osVersion":
          "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
      "playDate": "2022-06-29",
      "cinemaID": "1|0001|1013",
      "representationMovieCode": ""
    }
  };

  var req = await Dio().post(
    '$url',
    data: dic,
  );
  print(req);


  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

But the result is
[image]
-> 'ParamList가 존재하지 않습니다' =  'ParamList does not exist.'

Another code is this.

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:html/parser.dart';
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';

void main() async {
  var url = 'https://www.lottecinema.co.kr/LCWS/Ticketing/TicketingData.aspx';

  var dic = {
    "paramList": {
      "MethodName": "GetPlaySequence",
      "channelType": "HO",
      "osType": "W",
      "osVersion":
          "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
      "playDate": "2022-06-29",
      "cinemaID": "1|0001|1013",
      "representationMovieCode": ""
    }.toString()
  };

  var request = await http.MultipartRequest('Post', Uri.parse('$url'));
  request.fields.addAll(dic);

  http.StreamedResponse response = await request.send();
  var responseString = await response.stream.bytesToString();

  print("STATUS CODE : ${response.statusCode}");
  print("RESPONSE BODY : ${responseString}");

  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

[image]

The paramList  what i need and expected result are in this screenshot

[image]

[image]

how can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the api end point only accepts data in the `multipart/formdata` format.

```
import 'dart:covert';
...
  
String paramList = json.encode({
    "MethodName": "GetPlaySequence",
    "channelType": "HO",
    "osType": "W",
    "osVersion":
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
    "playDate": "2022-06-29",
    "cinemaID": "1|0001|1013",
    "representationMovieCode": ""
  });

FormData formData = FormData.fromMap({'ParamList': paramList});

var req = await Dio().post(
  '$url',
  data: formData,
);
```

Comment: I change code to "

FormData formData = FormData.fromMap({'ParamList': paramList});

  var req = await Dio().post(
    '$url',
    data: formData,
  );"   because "formData.append()" doesn't work.


But the result is 
flutter: {"IsOK":"false","ResultMessage":"Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: G. Path 'MethodName', line 1, position 13.","ResultCode":null,"EventResultYn":null}

Comment: do you know why that error occur?

Comment: I've updated my answer, please try that way. The issue is backend is failed to decode the input string into a valid json